# SVN Replace command for particular file

Tags: unix, svn, centos

There is file text.jsp in my branch. I want to commit this file into trunk.

I have done check out for trunk folder and i navigated to text.jsp file location in trunk folder.

What is the command to replace. I tried below command

svn replace text.jsp https://mybranch/text.jsp

What is right command in svn command prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to do it with `svn merge` command as it will keep the full commit log/history of your `text.jsp` file in trunk

`svn merge --accept theirs-full https://mybranch/text.jsp https://mytrunk/text.jsp`

If there are merge conflicts you are forcing to ignore them with `--accept theirs-full` option as you want to replace the file.

---

If you don't want to keep the full commit log of `text.jsp` file in trunk do it like this. (Note that this way the commit log will be started newly)

- `svn delete https://mytrunk/text.jsp`
- `svn copy https://mybranch/text.jsp https://mytrunk/text.jsp`
- `svn commit`

This way you'll avoid unnecessary hassle with branch/trunk checkout, exporting, moving and committing the file manually.

---

Alternatively you can do it also like this

1. Navigate to directory where your original `text.jsp` is (trunk version)
2. Export the "new" file `svn export https://mybranch/text.jsp`
3. As the name of your "new" file is the same as the one in your repository
   `svn` will automatically detect it as a modification. So you just
   need to commit it with `svn ci text.jsp`